# Hibernate generates cross join instead of left join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, left-join, cross-join

I'm using hibernate 3.6.10.Final and MySQL 5.5.

I wrote a dynamic query like this:

```
"from " + clazz.getName()+ " ORDER BY "+sortField+" "+sortDirection
```

My hibernate entities have a many to one parent/child relationship.
if the query is ordered by a field from parent, hibernate generates this hql select:

```
select parent0_.ID as ID10_, parent0_.ID_CHILD as ID6_10_ 
from parent parent0_
order by parent0_.PARENTFIELD ASC
```

if the query is ordered by a field from child, i have the following hql:

```
select parent0_.ID as ID10_, parent0_.ID_CHILD as ID6_10_
from parent parent0_
cross join child1_
where parent0_.ID_CHILD = child1_.ID
order by child1_.CHILDFIELD ASC
```

The second query returns less results because parent0_.ID_CHILD can be null.
Is there a way to force hibernate to generate a left join?

I need something like this

```
select parent0_.ID as ID10_,
   parent0_.ID_CHILD as ID6_10_
from
parent parent0_
    left join
child child1_
on
parent0_.ID_CHILD = child1_.ID
order by child1_.CHILDFIELD ASC
```

Comment: Is that an answer? I don't want to write a particular query for my parent and child entities. I want to reuse that generic query forcing hibernate to take parents with null child too.

Comment: Then you need a query with an explicit left join. There's no way around it. `child.parent.someProperty` will always generate an inner join. Read the documentation. It's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet i solved writing the query like this:

```
String[] tokens = sortField.split("\\.");
for(int i=0;i<tokens.length-1;i++)
{
    sortby+=" LEFT JOIN parent"+i+"."+tokens[i]+" as child"+i;
}
sortby+=" ORDER BY child"+(tokens.length-2)+"."+tokens[tokens.length-1]+" "+sortDirection;
...
String query = "select parent0 FROM " + clazz.getName()+" as parent0 "+ sortby;
```